# Android TV BackgroundManager not playing nicely with Bitmaps/Drawables and transparency

Tags: android, background, transparency, drawable, android-tv

Whilst applying drawables via the BackgroundManager I am noticing sever corruption of the UI. This only occurs when the drawable is partially transparent.

For reference the support library version number i'm seeing this on is 26.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this which may be helpful to others with the same issue. Using a layered drawable prevents the corruption.

```
  Drawable[] layers = {ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable
                    .white_background), drawable};
                    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
                    mBackgroundManager.setDrawable(layerDrawable);
```